# Definition of two-dimensional white noise process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, independence

A process $(X_{t})_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is *one-dimensional white noise* if

- $\mathbb{E}[X_{t}] = 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{Z}$,
- $\operatorname{Var}(X_{t}) = \sigma^{2} < \infty$ for all $t \in \mathbb{Z}$,
- $\operatorname{Cov}(X_{s},X_{t}) = 0$ for all $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $s \neq t$.

So far, so clear. But what is a *two-dimensional white noise process*? I have seen two different definitions:

**Definition 1.** A process 
$$ \big( X_{t} = (X_{t}^{1},X_{t}^{2}) \big)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$$
is called a *two-dimensional white noise process* if its components $(X^{1}_{t})_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ and $(X^{2}_{t})_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ are independent of each other and white noise processes itself.

**Definition 2.** A process 
$$ \big( X_{t} = (X_{t}^{1},X_{t}^{2}) \big)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$$
is called a *two-dimensional white noise process* if its components $(X^{1}_{t})_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ and $(X^{2}_{t})_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ are white noise processes satisfying
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X_{t}^{1},X_{t}^{2}) = \sigma_{12} \qquad \text{and} \qquad
\operatorname{Cov}(X_{s}^{1},X_{t}^{2}) = 0 \text{ for } s \neq t.
$$

I have two questions:

1. Is it right that these two definitions are different? I think in the second definition the independence of the components is not satisfied because otherwise we would need that $\operatorname{Cov}(X_{t}^{1},X_{t}^{2}) = 0$.
2. Which definition is more common? The first definition seems natural to me, because in a similar way multi-dimensional Brownian motion is defined. However, in time series analysis I could almost exclusively find the second definition.